# Which constructs in TypeScript contain more than just type information?

Tags: typescript

So far I have been using TypeScript in a way such that it enhances or annotates JavaScript code with type information. For example, adding the expected type of function parameters or return values.
But one construct seems to be different: [`enum`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html)

`enum` seems different because it does not merely enhance an existing JavaScript construct with type information, but it actually creates a piece of data on its own.

Example:

```
enum OBJ {
  A = 1,
  B = 2,
}
```

I can treat `OBJ` as a piece of data. Eg. I can `console.log(OBJ)` or assign `OBJ.A` to a variable, whereas I cannot `console.log` other TypeScript constructs like a `type` or an `interface`.

Are there more examples like `enum` in TypeScript which declare more than just type information and have no equivalent in JavaScript?

Also, is there a name for this class of TypeScript language features to which `enum` belongs (which declare more than just type information and have no equivalent in JavaScript)?

Comment: Try adding `const` in front of `enum` in your example and observe the magic

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean? Adding `const` in front is still unlike a JavaScript `const`, which requires an `=` sign and a right hand side of the expression

Comment: Another obvious example: a `class` both declares a type and constructs a tangible JS value.

Comment: All Typescript compiles to Javascript, so there is nothing which has *"no equivalent"* in Javascript. But Typescript has some syntax which is compiled to different Javascript syntax rather than just stripped out (like type declarations and annotations are). The term for these things is "syntax sugar".

Comment: Have a look [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#basic-concepts) for a division of declarations like `enum` to the groups `namespace`, `type` and `value`.